# Set many variables to the same: Adding to one variable adds to many

Tags: python, list

I wanted to efficiently set a bunch of variables to an empty list. However, using this method, operations on one variable seem to apply to all:

```
>>> r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8=[[]]*8
>>> r1
[]
>>> r1+=[2]
>>> r1,r2
([2], [2])
```

Why is this? Also, what is the most efficient method that leaves each variable independent?

Comment: Why not just have a list of lists? As opposed to 8 variables? Or even a dictionary?

Comment: @Ffisegydd interesting. Question about what you linked: If the syntax [x]*4 creates a 4 item list whose contents all reference the same object, why doesn't [[x]*4]*2 do the same, but with 8 objects total? Why was only the first element of each inner list changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `[[]]*8` creates a list of eight references to the same list object.  That is why they all get affected when you update one.  To make eight unique lists, use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8 = ([] for _ in range(8))
```

You might also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8 = [[] for _ in range(8)]
```